# How to write Junit test cases for this class

Tags: spring-boot

```
@DeleteMapping(value = "/{id}", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Void> delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
    log.debug("Delete by id Logo : {}", id);

    try {
        Logo entr = new Logo();
        entr.setId(id);
        logoRepository.delete(entr);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    } catch (Exception x) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends, you want a unit test or an integration test?

Comment: For Integration testing

Answer (score 0):

For testing controllers we could mock mvc. Inject mock of service layers inside the controller.

Since you have mock for your service you could mock the response that service should return for a transaction using Mockito.when statement.

A sample code will be like.

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @WebMvcTest(controllers = HelloController.class)
    public class HelloWorldTest {

        @Autowired
        private MockMvc mockMvc;

        @MockBean
        private HelloService service;

        @Test
        public void testShouldReturnMessage() throws Exception {

        when(service.sayHello()).thenReturn("Hello World");

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/hello").accept(MediaType.ALL))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().is(200))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().string("Hello World"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.header().string("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.header().string("Content-Length", "11"));
    }
}
```

Reference - [https://www.nexsoftsys.com/articles/spring-boot-controller-unit-testing.html#:~:text=Unit%20testing%20Spring%20Boot%20controllers%20Technology%20Unit%20testing,is%20to%20validate%20each%20unit%20performs%20as%20designed](https://www.nexsoftsys.com/articles/spring-boot-controller-unit-testing.html#:%7E:text=Unit%20testing%20Spring%20Boot%20controllers%20Technology%20Unit%20testing,is%20to%20validate%20each%20unit%20performs%20as%20designed).